# Horizontall scrolling gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I just noticed on [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html) that there is also a `horizontally scrolling grid list`. I tested it using the regular gridview, but it only has vertical scrolling.

Does anybody know which widget this is?

Comment: Copying my G+ comment here: There isn't currently a framework widget that provides this, but something similar can be achieved with Renderscript and the CarouselView example code

Comment: Thanks Roman. Just filed a feature request. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26238
Please star this issue, if you want this widget to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a linearLayout inside a gridView that would represent each cell of the gridView and then set a minWidth for the linearLayout. This would handle the fact that each cell of that gridView would have to have a minWidth of say 5dp.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:rowCount="2">

</GridLayout>
```